# Error when run EXEC procedure in T-SQL Statement Task

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, database-backups

I created few procedures that I want to run using Maintenance Plan's `Execute T-SQL Statement Task` box however I'm getting error that job is not found.

**Maintenance Task's configuration**:
[image]

Returned error for running `EXEC [dbo].[sp_backup_full] N'db_name', N'path/where//to/store/backup'`:

```
End Progress  Error: 2021-06-29 18:59:00.42     Code: 0xC002F210     Source: full_backup_and_delete_old_one Execute SQL Task     
Description: Executing the query "EXEC [dbo].[sp_backup_full] N'db_name..." failed with the following error: "Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.sp_backup_full'.". 
Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
```

Comment: Perhaps the local server connection is dropping you into a different database. Have you tried `EXEC [YourDatabaseName].[dbo].[sp_backup_full] ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont specify the databasename, by default, it is run in the `master` database. You can give three part name for the stored procedure call, to make sure that it is using the right database for execution.

```sql
EXEC [DatabaseName].[dbo].[sp_backup_full]
```